# In Angular 2 how to put array string elements into template element value-attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I have this array called myArray in my Angular 2 component class:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'my.component.html'
})

export class MyComponent {
    private myArray: Array<string>;
    ...
}
```

In my.component.html I have a single input element:

```
<input placeholder='write some tags' value=''>
```

What I want is to have the string elements of myArray inserted into the value attribute of the input element. The strings should be comma separated. Something like:

```
<input placeholder='write some tags' value='apple, orange, banana'>
```

I tried:

```
<input name='user-tag' placeholder='write some tags' value='*ngFor="let e of myArray"{{e}}'>
```

But that produced an error.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No need to use `*ngFor`, try using [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```
<input name='user-tag' placeholder='write some tags' value='{{ myArray.join(', ') }}'>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to create a filter to do this kind of thing so you will have a single point of ref and when some improvement is needed you won't need to change more than one place.

Comment: Absolutely, a [pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) would be ideal for what you're describing, but I didn't want to over architect the answer.